# Is there Intent Filter for Cellular State Changed?

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, cellular-network

I'm trying to receive info about the Carrier name to which network the device is currently connected. For that I'm using the simple code:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) aContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

To not do any stupid work like polling this info every X ms, I'm trying to register some receiver which would be invoked whenever some event occurs which is connected with the above info. For that I was using a receiver with action set in intent filter in manifest as such:

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

Whenever I change the roaming operator a receiver is being invoked with appropriate intent. All great as long as it's in the context of Data Transfer. As soon as I connect to WiFi or disable Mobile Data altogether, this receiver stops being invoked when I change the roaming operator.

Is there any smart way (without polling this data every X ms) that I can get the carrier's name whenever the device is registered to another cellular operator?

Comment: `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` is fired on data connetivity changes. That's not what you want. Try using `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED`. I'm not sure if this will fire when the carrier changes, but I would think so. Try it.

Comment: Also see `TelephonyManager` for more info about SIM_STATE

Comment: Thanks David. I added the action filter as such: "                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />", unfortunetly it doesn't trigger the receiver when I go to and from flight mode.

Comment: For flight mode you need to listen for `android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE`

Comment: No no, what I meant is that people who listened to that intent said it should react to any SIM state changed, which includes going on/off from Flight mode.

Comment: Yes, I would have assunmed that `SIM_STATE_CHANGED` would be broadcast when you go in and out of flight mode.